# Retrieve data from database without hard coding in Yii syntax

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I am trying to get the data from database and use it in a condition in the if statement but its not working. and i can't figure out why. Please help me. 
The one i am trying is this and it doesn't work.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = '`label1`= '.$this->label1;
$model2 = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

I am using Yii 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = 'label1 = :label1';
$criteria->params = array(':label1'=> $this->label1);
$model2 = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);

// see Documentation https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria
```